# Data Tables:How to control the <th> width of table . I am Using Jquery -1.9.4 version

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, datatables

Is it possible to control or set the width which adding to table header as an line css. I am trying to check it from the  dataTables-jquery of version 1.9.4 .But couldn't find any solution.Due to the adding of width the  alignment is getting disturbed.

I am also assigning the width in the HTML like

```
<th width="20%">Bhairav</th>
```

But when i am checking in the console it appears like

```
<th width="20%" class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="" style="width: 12px;">Bhairav</th>
```

Issue is the style="width: 12px;" is adding to it dynamically from nowhere.?

Can anyone please help me solving the issue.

Comment: Try assigning it like `<th style="width:20%;">Bhairav</th>`

Comment: Or better yet, remove the inline styling and throw the CSS in a stylesheet.

Comment: @lee i tried with it but still the issue remains same.

Comment: @Prgmr i didn't get what you said?

Comment: @lee now when i check it in console it appears like this

Comment: <th style="width: 12px;" class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="">Bhairav</th>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`style="width: 12px;"` is added by dataTables when it have `bAutoWidth: true`.  Example :

dataTables 1.9.4 with default `bAutowidth`  (true) -> **http://jsfiddle.net/rrsn0ckL/**

first `<th>` is rendered as

```
<th width="30%" class="sorting_asc" ...style="width: 254px;">Rendering engine</th>
```

same table with `bAutoWidth: false` -> **http://jsfiddle.net/rrsn0ckL/1/**

first `<th>` is rendered as

```
<th width="30%" class="sorting_asc" ...>Rendering engine</th>
```

so use `bAutoWidth: false` to avoid the `style="width: 12px;"`

---

**Notice** : The `<th>` `width` attribute is HTML 4.01 specific and should no longer be used -> **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th**

Instead use CSS or inline styling as `style="width:20%;"`. CSS example :

```css
table#example th:nth-child(1) {
    width: 20%;
}
table#example th:nth-child(2) {
    width: 20%;
}
```

etc.